# How to avoid messy nested if-else or switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested, switch-statement, polymorphism

```
Function AM()
{
  var source = new Array("External","Chassis","Internal");
  var shape = new Array("Sine","Square", "Ramp","Nramp","Triangle","ARB");
  var depth = new Array ("100","0","50");
  var frequency = new Array("100","0.002","20000","1000");

  var currentSource;
  var currentShape;
  var currentDepth;
  var currentFrequency;

  for (var item in source)
  {
    currentSource = source[item];
    FG_AMSource().Keys(source[item] );

    for (var item in shape)
    {
      currentShape = shape[item];
      FG_AMShape().Keys(shape[item] );

      for (var item in depth)
      {
        currentDepth = depth[item];
        FG_AMDepth().Keys(depth[item]);

        for (var item in frequency)
        {
          currentFrequency = item;
          FG_AM_Frequency().Keys(frequency[item]);
          CheckImage2(currentSource, currentShape,currentDepth, currentFrequency);
        }// shape
      }// depth
    }// shape
  }//source
}
```

`FG_AMSource()` is a function that allows me to set the setting. With what I have here, I am able to loop through all combinations of Source, Shape, Depth and Frequency.
My problem here lies in the `CheckImage2` function. With each combination I get, I must call this `CheckImage2` function, pass in the current Source, Shape, Depth and Frequency, then do checking accordingly. Therefore, inside my `CheckImage2` function, it will look something like

```
Function CheckImage2(currentSource, currentShape, currentDepth, currentFrequency)
{
    switch (currentSource)
        case "External":
            switch (currentShape)
                case "Sine":
                    switch (currentDepth)
                        case "100":
                            switch (currentFrequency)
                                case "100": //External+Sine+100+100
                                case "0.002": //External+Sine+100+0.002
                                //etc etc etc you get the idea
                                //and I need to include all possible combinations
}
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: break it up into separate functions.

Comment: I don't get it. What is this function doing at all, what does it return? What are these `FG_AM…().Keys(…)` calls, are they relevant somehow?

Comment: Could you post the complete code, please? Currently your `case`s are empty, so simplifying them would be trivial.

Comment: Don't you want `currentFrequency = frequency[item];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to get around with it:

1) If the action can be **formulated**, then you should create the formula rather than creating nested `for` loop or `switch`. Something like

```
Function CheckImage2(currentSource, currentShape, currentDepth, currentFrequency)
{
    //example, suppose it can be formulated as a string
    string formulatedString = currentSource + currentShape + currentDepth + currentFrequency; 
    //do something else, because things can be formulated instead of listed
}
```

This is because what you actually need is a handler/function which takes any of the combination.

2) If the number of combination is not that many to populate, try using `HashMap` or `Map` or whatever equivalent and **pre-populate the possible combinations** such that when you use you simply need to call `hashMap[key]` and at most 1 `for` loop then act accordingly instead of having nested loops

3) Whenever possible, you can also break them into pieces of **smaller independent functions** which depend only on one (or at least fewer) element at a time (rather than all of them).

4) Consider of creating a proper class and **using `Tree` structure** to work around with it